# replace values in a pandas dataframe (excluding missing values)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null, conditional-statements

I been trying to get my code to work but I am having some trouble here.  It would be great if someone could assist me

DF

```
  Col1              Col2          
  2017-01-01        Coffee
  2017-01-01        Muffin
  2017-01-01        Donut
  2017-01-01        Toast
  2017-01-01        
  2017-01-01
```

How can I change Col2 so that every value that isn't Coffee or Muffin or null becomes 'Other'?

```
  Col1              Col2          
  2017-01-01        Coffee
  2017-01-01        Muffin
  2017-01-01        Other
  2017-01-01        Other
  2017-01-01        
  2017-01-01
```

Edit:

```
df.loc[~df.Col2.isin(['Coffee','Muffin']), 'Col2'] = 'Other'
```

^this is where I am right now, but how can I add a null statement in the isin

Comment: "get my code to work" - please include your code.

Comment: Is that NaN or an empty string? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: it is blank, missing value according to df.describe()

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. If you're working with NaNs, you'll need an additional check with `isnull`. Create a mask and set values with `loc` -

```
m = ~(df.Col2.isin(['Coffee', 'Muffin']) | df.Col2.isnull())
df.loc[m, 'Col2'] = 'Other'

df

         Col1    Col2
0  2017-01-01  Coffee
1  2017-01-01  Muffin
2  2017-01-01   Other
3  2017-01-01   Other
4  2017-01-01     NaN
5  2017-01-01     NaN
```

Or, if they're blanks (empty string, not NaN - they're different!), perform an equality comparison for the second condition -

```
m = ~(df.Col2.isin(['Coffee', 'Muffin']) | df.Col2.eq(''))
```

---

Here are some more possibilities with `np.where`/`pd.Series.where`/`pd.Series.mask` -

```
df.Col2 = np.where(m, 'Other', df.Col2)
```

Or,

```
df.Col2 = df.Col2.where(~m, 'Other')
```

Or,

```
df.Col2 = df.Col2.mask(m, 'Other')
```

```
df

         Col1    Col2
0  2017-01-01  Coffee
1  2017-01-01  Muffin
2  2017-01-01   Other
3  2017-01-01   Other
4  2017-01-01     NaN
5  2017-01-01     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01'],
 'Col2':['Coffee','Muffin','Donut','Toast',pd.np.nan,pd.np.nan]})

conditions = (df['Col2'] != 'Coffee') & (df['Col2'] != 'Muffin') & (df['Col2'].isnull() == False)

df['Col2'][conditions] = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 2):

`isin` can include the `np.nan`

```
df.loc[df.Col2.isin(['Donut', 'Toast',np.nan]),'Col2']='Other'
df
Out[112]: 
         Col1    Col2
0  2017-01-01  Coffee
1  2017-01-01  Muffin
2  2017-01-01   Other
3  2017-01-01   Other
4  2017-01-01   Other
5  2017-01-01   Other
```

Comment: df.loc[df.Col2.isin(['Coffee', 'Muffin',pd.np.nan]) == False,'Col2']='Other'